# STL не работает multimap::equal_range()

Tags: stl, qt, c++

изучаю STL, работаю с multimap:

```
typedef multimap<string, string> str_mmap;
str_mmap test_mmap;
string str1("1"), str2("2"), s("1");
test_mmap.insert(str1, str1);
test_mmap.insert(str2, str2);
test_mmap.insert(str1, str2);
pair<str_mmap::iterator, str_mmap::iterator> finded = test_mmap.equal_range(s);
```

последняя строка выдает ошибку, которая возникает внутри STL:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:1732: ошибка: no match for 'operator++' (operand type is 'std::basic_string<char>')
for (; __first != __last; ++__first)

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:1733: ошибка: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'std::basic_string<char>')
    _M_insert_equal_(end(), *__first);
                        ^
```

Компилятор: QT 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем разобрался сам, парился 2 дня, ошибка возникала в insert, в пятницу причем она там не возникала (комментил equal_range и вызывал просто find)

итак:

```
test_mmap.insert(make_pair(str1, str1));
test_mmap.insert(make_pair(str2, str2));
test_mmap.insert(make_pair(str1, str2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте объявить итератор вот так:

```
pair <multimap<string, string>::iterator, multimap<string, string>::iterator> finded = test_mmap.equal_range(s);
```